# IdentityServer4 - Deleting expired persistent grants

Tags: identityserver4

Is this handled automatically somehow or should I have a scheduled job that deletes these periodically? I suppose keeping them for audit purposes makes sense but revocation does a hard delete so I don't think that's the intent of this table/entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if the EF implementation of persistent grants comes with a scheduled job, but that should be easy to verify by looking at what EF creates. We are using a different ORM to manage our grants table, so in that case yes - we would need to create a scheduled job to clean up that table.

Answer (score 10):

This works for me:

```
services.AddIdentityServer().AddOperationalStore(options =>
                                         {
                                             options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                                             options.TokenCleanupInterval = 3600; // 1 hour
                                         });
```

Comment: I think this feature was added in a later version. I had Hangfire in play anyway so I just implemented a scheduled job that runs every night.

Comment: @mackie cool, just thought I'd post it anyways in case anyone else comes along with the same problem :)